# Sanic request validation using Pydantic: Exception occurred while handling uri:

Tags: python, validation, pydantic, sanic

I have followed the example at https://sanic.dev/en/plugins/sanic-ext/validation.html#validation-with-pydantic to implement validation on my Sanic routes using Pydantic.

If I make a request to the route with valid request paramaters, the code executes successfully, without issue.

If I make a request to the route with a 'payment' parameter that doesn't conform to the Pydantic 'ValidatePayment' class definition, Sanic responds to the request indicating a validation error, as follows:

```
{
  "description": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "message": "Invalid request body: ValidatePayment. Error: 1 validation error for ValidatePayment\npayment\n  invalid payment... (type=value_error)"
}
```

So far, this is good, however, when Sanic responds with the above Validation error, it's also throwing / outputting the following exception to the console, suggesting that multiple exceptions haven't been caught / handled correctly:

```
| [2022-03-27 17:45:38 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception occurred while handling uri: 'http://localhost:5001/pay'
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sanic_ext/extras/validation/validators.py", line 24, in validate_body
|     return validator(model, body)
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sanic_ext/extras/validation/validators.py", line 32, in _validate_instance
|     return model(**body)
|   File "pydantic/main.py", line 331, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
| pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for ValidatePayment
| payment
|   invalid payment... (type=value_error)
| 
| During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
| 
| Traceback (most recent call last):
|   File "handle_request", line 83, in handle_request
|     )
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sanic_ext/extensions/openapi/openapi.py", line 213, in handler
|     retval = await retval
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sanic_ext/extras/validation/decorator.py", line 37, in decorated_function
|     await do_validation(
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sanic_ext/extras/validation/setup.py", line 41, in do_validation
|     validation = validate_body(validator, model, data)
|   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sanic_ext/extras/validation/validators.py", line 26, in validate_body
|     raise ValidationError(
| sanic_ext.exceptions.ValidationError: Invalid request body: ValidatePayment. Error: 1 validation error for ValidatePayment
```

If possible, I would be grateful to know why this exception is happening in the console, and how I can properly handle it.

Here is the code for the route definition:

```
@app.route("/pay", methods=['POST'])
@validate(json=ValidatePayment)
async def pay(request):

    ...

    response = {
        "status": 200,
        ...
    }

    return json(response, 200)
```

And here is the code for the Pydantic validation class:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class ValidatePayment(BaseModel):
    payment: str

    @validator('payment')
    def valid_payment(cls, v):
        if v[0:4] != "...." and v[0:4] != "----":
            raise ValueError(f'invalid payment...')
        return v
```

Answer (score 2):

So after some more searching and reading, I have come up with two possible solutions.

The first is to add custom exception handling, either to each individual route, or as a single catch-all handler, using the app.exception decorator, as described here:
https://sanic.dev/en/guide/best-practices/exceptions.html#handling

A cleaner solution, however, seems to be to have the Pydantic validation class raise a SanicException, as opposed to raising a ValueError. For example, this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class ValidatePayment(BaseModel):
    payment: str

    @validator('payment')
    def valid_payment(cls, v):
        if v[0:4] != "...." and v[0:4] != "----":
            raise ValueError(f'invalid payment...')
        return v
```

Becomes this:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator
from sanic.exceptions import SanicException

class ValidatePayment(BaseModel):
    payment: str

    @validator('payment')
    def valid_payment(cls, v):
        if v[0:4] != "...." and v[0:4] != "----":
            raise SanicException('Invalid payment...', status_code=400)
        return v
```

When doing this, the client still receives the validation failure notice, and there is no unhandled exception in the Sanic console / log.